# I got this error on postman: "status": 404, "error": "Not Found", "message": "No message available",

Tags: spring, spring-boot

here is my  controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/product")
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService service;

    @PostMapping("/addProduct")
    public Product addProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        return service.saveProduct(product);
    }

    @PostMapping("/addProducts")
    public List<Product> addProduct(@RequestBody List<Product> products) {
        return service.saveProduct(products);
    }

    @PutMapping("/update")
    public void updateProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        service.updateProduct(product);
    }

    @GetMapping("/products")
    public List<Product> findAllProducts() {
        return service.getProducts();
    }

    @GetMapping("/getProductById/{id}")
    public Product getProductById(@PathVariable int id) {
        return service.getProductById(id);
    }

    @GetMapping("/getProductByName/{name}")
    public Product getProduct(@PathVariable String name) {
        return service.getProductByName(name);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public void deleteProduct(@PathVariable int id) {
        service.deleteProduct(id);
    }

}
```

I got errors when I try to request methods in postman

Comment: can you attach request url from postman?

Comment: Hi, it would be useful to provide more context. What are you trying to do? what services are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't have a @GetMapping for /product.

You only have:

```
@GetMapping("/products")
```

Try that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add /product before your endpoint as your controller has the annotation:
 `@RequestMapping("/product")`.

call your endpoint in Postman with :

`http://domainName:port/product/products`

For example with domain name *localhost* and port *8080* you will have: `http://localhost:8080`

> Please also make sure that you are calling with correct HTTP
>   method, GET, POST, or PUT